# 0-1 sequences without repeating 1's

Tags: c

My task is to write a program, where the input is an exponent of 2, and the output is the number of sequences (out of the maximum 2^n sequences) where there are no 1's next to each other. (n<=50)

For example, on the input of 3, the output is 5, because 2^3=8 and out of the 8 possibilities the only acceptable ones are: (000, 001, 010, 100, 101) and (110,011,111) are not acceptable because there are 2 or more 1's next to each other.

My program works fine until 31, upon the number 32 it stops working, overflow issues I guess. I tried long int and unsigned int, none of those seemed to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
    int t,i,n,j,ki;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for (i=1;i<=t;i++){
            scanf("%d",&n);
            ki=pow(2,n)-(n*(n-1))/2;
            printf("Scenario #%d:\n%d\n\n",i,ki);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Help me pl0x.

Comment: 2^32 - 1 is the maximum value of int. You have pow(2,32).

Comment: Use int64_t instead of int, otherwise if ints are only 32 bits then you will get overflow.

Comment: In C, (1 << n), rather than pow(2,n), is the more idiomatic (and efficient) way to express integer powers of 2.

Comment: I wonder if that formula can really give the correct number... For `n == 4`, `ki` is `16 - 6 = 10`, but I can only come up with 8 valid permutations: **(0)** `0000` **(1)** `0001` **(2)** `0010` **(3)** `0100` **(4)** `1000` **(5)** `0101` **(6)** `1001` **(7)** `1010` **(8)**

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. Using long long int and %lld fixed the overflow problem, but now you made me realise that my formula is also bad :D.

Comment: @user3390443 Want me to come up with a proper formula, or would you like to find it out yourself?

Comment: I'm rather desperate here, if you have a solution I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Hint: Think about the problem recursively. That is: suppose you already had the solution for problems of size 1, 2, 3, ... up to n - 1.  If you had all that information, could you solve it for n?

Comment: @user3390443 The answer is hidden inside Fibonacci numbers: Let `F(x)` be the xth Fibonacci number, your answer for any `n` is `F(n) + F(n+1)`

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: That was going to be my next hint. :-) If you write out the cases for n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 it becomes very apparent that they are all Fibonacci numbers. Do you see why they are?

Comment: @EricLippert Meh, sorry, I don't know, he said he wanted it... user3390443, I recommend you writing down the valid permutations for single digit, which would be `0` and `1`. After that, write two copies of those permutations, prefix the first copies with `0`s, then prefix the second copies with `1`s, eliminate the invalid ones. Do this for a couple of times, you'll realize that you have eliminated only when you prefix `1`s, and you'll possibly also realize that you have done it only for numbers that had their first digit as `1`. Then write down the `startswith1:startswith0` ratio for each `n`.

Comment: If you're planning on brute-forcing this (which I wouldnt), no matter what the value, so long as it is > 0 `(val & (val >> 1))` will be 0 if it matches your criteria for 1's. I leave the reverse of that to you to figure out with the hint that you can flip all the 0's to 1's and vice-versa with `~val`.

Comment: So now I have added a simple recursive Fibonacci function to the program, and ki=fibonacci(n)+fibonacci(n+1) as @ThoAppelsin said. Problem once again occurs, when I try to upload it to my prof's auto-checking site and it times out after a while, probably doesn't like to calculate the 50th Fibonacci number or so.

Comment: I may not be able to pin-point the problem without seeing the current code, however I can say that even F(90) can be stored inside an 64 bit integer. One suggestion, why don't you pre-calculate and store the first 50~90 Fibonacci numbers, so you won't make the computer calculate F(n) (at least) twice, more precisely, each F(n) ( nmax - n + 2 ) times?

Comment: Naively calculating the nth fib number recursively takes *that many calculations*. That is, calculating fib(5) to get 8 takes 8 calculations; calculating fib(20) to get 6765 takes 6765 calculations. **Use an iterative solution.**

Comment: Changed the recursive function to a simple iterative one, it is working perfectly now. Also, the auto-checking site accepted it in seconds. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For variable `ki`:**

Step #1: Use `unsigned long long` instead of `int`.

Step #2: Use `1<<n` instead of `pow(2,n)`.

Step #3: Use `llu%` instead of `%d`.

```
int main()
{
    int t,i,n;
    unsigned long long ki,one=1;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for (i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        ki = (one<<n)-n*(n-1)/2;
        printf("Scenario #%d:\n%llu\n\n",i,ki);
    }
    return 0;
}
```